# What does 'on the curve' mean?

Tags: meaning

Mike Birbiglia said about George W.Bush:

`"He is the first president we've elected on the curve".`

("What I should've said was nothing" show)

Google wasn't helpful, couldn't find 'on the curve' in online dictionaries.

Now, I'm wondering if I misheard it, but I'm 99% sure he said on the curve.

Comment: There are a number of expressions and metaphors related to curves; what is the full context? And note that doing something on *a curve* may differ from doing something on *the curve*; out of context, *grading on a curve* means to adjust scores to map against a normal distribution, whereas *grading on the curve* refers to the degree of slope on a curved portion of road.

Comment: Yes, it is on the curve, not on a curve. He told a story about passing a class in the college despite missing the finals, and he said - I am proud to be an American, and so is our president. It's true, he is the first president we've elected on the curve. -- And the whole audience laughed. So I thought was some sort of common slang expression.

Comment: And apparently what he said is funny on its own without any context, so I think it's something to do with his personality. [Here is the link](http://timetoputonashow.tumblr.com/post/35075678627/hes-the-first-president-weve-elected-on-the)

Comment: In my experience (which, granted, dates 45-55 years back), US students usually hoped they would be graded on ***the** curve* - that is, on the  'bell-shaped' curve representing a normalized distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StoneyB is right about the origin of the phrase "on the curve."  It comes from assigning letter grades ABCDF based on the (assumed) normal distribution of students' numerical scores instead of on a linear scale of A=90-100, B=80-90, C=70-80, etc.  It has come to mean adjusting the grading to boost lower scores that would have been failing under a linear system into the passing range (although that isn't what necessarily what would happen in the mathematical sense of the term).

The quote means that under previous, supposedly more rigorous, considerations of Presidential candidates, W wouldn't have been elected President, but under the easier "curved grading," was given passing marks that made him electable.

Perhaps an example would help.  Suppose that the average grade of C on a test is pegged to 70% correct answers, and the test is very difficult.  The average score comes in at 50, but that's a failing grade on the linear scale.  The class will beg the teacher to grade **on a curve**, making 50 a C.

Comment: That totally makes sense

Comment: @MarinaDunst Specifically, he won without a majority or even a plurality of the popular vote, by virtue of a very contentious series of legal decisions which forestalled manual recount of contested votes in Florida.

Comment: W's winning the presidency without winning the popular vote was [not itself entirely unprecedented](http://www.factcheck.org/2008/03/presidents-winning-without-popular-vote/); but Birbiglia's joke would seem to reside in a *combination* of that unusual circumstance with W's positive embracing of his own mediocrity as a student, a C student.